# Parameter @Something Has No Default Value (Access Database, Visual Studio VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, ms-access, parameters, oledb

I am using an Access Database to store records of occurrences of errors to track their quantity and frequency. Thanks to some great help from some gifted programmers on this site, I am now getting closer to my end goal of pulling the occurrence counts back out of the database, and into charts in an Visual Studio program.

The problem I'm running into is that there is an error being thrown at this line in my function:

> count = command.ExecuteScalar()

The error is as follows:

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Parameter @MY_OF_LOG has no default value.'

I am successfully returning a value for count, which is 0. This is a possible value, but I am now wondering if the fact that the count returns as zero is what might be partially contributing to this error?

*Note: the values that will be returned from these counts for each month will be used as y values for a chart.*

Does anyone have any ideas on why this error occurred? I will insert a snippet of my code below. Thanks for the help.

```
Private Function CountMissedParts() Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim sql = $"SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM DataCollection
        WHERE [MISSED PART] = 'Missed Part'
        AND [M/Y OF LOG] = @MY_OF_LOG;"
    Dim JANmyOfLog = #1/1/2021#
    Dim FEBmyOfLog = #2/1/2021#
    Dim MARmyOfLog = #3/1/2021#
    Dim APRmyOfLog = #4/1/2021#
    Dim MAYmyOfLog = #5/1/2021#
    Dim JUNmyOfLog = #6/1/2021#
    Dim JULmyOfLog = #7/1/2021#
    Dim AUGmyOfLog = #8/1/2021#
    Dim SEPmyOfLog = #9/1/2021#
    Dim OCTmyOfLog = #10/1/2021#
    Dim NOVmyOfLog = #11/1/2021#
    Dim DECmyOfLog = #12/1/2021#
    Dim count As Integer
    Dim JanuaryMP As Double
    Dim FebruaryMP As Double
    Dim MarchMP As Double
    Dim AprilMP As Double
    Dim MayMP As Double
    Dim JuneMP As Double
    Dim JulyMP As Double
    Dim AugustMP As Double
    Dim SeptemberMP As Double
    Dim OctoberMP As Double
    Dim NovemberMP As Double
    Dim DecemberMP As Double

    Using connection As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Database1.accdb"),
            command As New OleDbCommand(sql, connection)
        JanuaryMP = command.Parameters.Add("@MY_OF_LOG", OleDbType.Date).Value = JANmyOfLog
        FebruaryMP = command.Parameters.Add("@MY_OF_LOG", OleDbType.Date).Value = FEBmyOfLog
        MarchMP = command.Parameters.Add("@MY_OF_LOG", OleDbType.Date).Value = MARmyOfLog
        AprilMP = command.Parameters.Add("@MY_OF_LOG", OleDbType.Date).Value = APRmyOfLog
        MayMP = command.Parameters.Add("@MY_OF_LOG", OleDbType.Date).Value = MAYmyOfLog
        JuneMP = command.Parameters.Add("@MY_OF_LOG", OleDbType.Date).Value = JUNmyOfLog
        JulyMP = command.Parameters.Add("@MY_OF_LOG", OleDbType.Date).Value = JULmyOfLog
        AugustMP = command.Parameters.Add("@MY_OF_LOG", OleDbType.Date).Value = AUGmyOfLog
        SeptemberMP = command.Parameters.Add("@MY_OF_LOG", OleDbType.Date).Value = SEPmyOfLog
        OctoberMP = command.Parameters.Add("@MY_OF_LOG", OleDbType.Date).Value = OCTmyOfLog
        NovemberMP = command.Parameters.Add("@MY_OF_LOG", OleDbType.Date).Value = NOVmyOfLog
        DecemberMP = command.Parameters.Add("@MY_OF_LOG", OleDbType.Date).Value = DECmyOfLog
        connection.Open()
        count = command.ExecuteScalar()

        ' set 0,0
        NotInEpicorCHRT.Series("Missed Part").Points.AddXY(0, 0)
        ' other points
        NotInEpicorCHRT.Series("Missed Part").Points.AddXY(1, JanuaryMP)

        NotInEpicorCHRT.Series("Missed Part").Points.AddXY(2, FebruaryMP)

        NotInEpicorCHRT.Series("Missed Part").Points.AddXY(3, MarchMP)

        NotInEpicorCHRT.Series("Missed Part").Points.AddXY(4, AprilMP)

        NotInEpicorCHRT.Series("Missed Part").Points.AddXY(5, MayMP)

        NotInEpicorCHRT.Series("Missed Part").Points.AddXY(6, JuneMP)

        NotInEpicorCHRT.Series("Missed Part").Points.AddXY(7, JulyMP)

        NotInEpicorCHRT.Series("Missed Part").Points.AddXY(8, AugustMP)

        NotInEpicorCHRT.Series("Missed Part").Points.AddXY(9, SeptemberMP)

        NotInEpicorCHRT.Series("Missed Part").Points.AddXY(10, OctoberMP)

        NotInEpicorCHRT.Series("Missed Part").Points.AddXY(11, NovemberMP)

        NotInEpicorCHRT.Series("Missed Part").Points.AddXY(12, DecemberMP)

    End Using
    NotInEpicorCHRT.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Minimum = 0.0
    NotInEpicorCHRT.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Maximum = 12
    NotInEpicorCHRT.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Interval = 1
    NotInEpicorCHRT.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.Minimum = 0.0
    NotInEpicorCHRT.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.Maximum = 45
    NotInEpicorCHRT.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.Interval = 5

End Function
```

Comment: You are adding multiple parameters of the same name whereas your SQL only needs one parameter

Comment: If I'm trying to pull them for multiple months can I not replicate the @MY_OF_LOG? Is there a way to get around that - I am trying to pull these values for each month, as those values serve as y values in my chart.

Comment: Options that I can think of are: 1. Run the Sql multiple times with different values each time. 2. Change the Sql so that it works differently with multiple parameters. I think for what you want Option 1 would be the quickest/simplest choice

Comment: Do you happen to have an example of how I could excecute the first option? I apologize, I am still very new to vb.net.

Comment: Did you look at my answer to your last question?

Comment: Why is this a Function? It has no datatype and  no return statement.

Comment: `JanuaryMP = command.Parameters.Add("@MY_OF_LOG", OleDbType.Date).Value = JANmyOfLog` What do you think this is doing? The .Value = sets the value of a parameter added to the parameters collection of the command. But, what do you think is JanuaryMP? BTW Count returns an Integer not a Double. How could there be a count of 1.5 records?

Comment: Of the dozen values you have assigned to the same parameter, which one do you think the code should pick for single .Execute?

Comment: .ExecuteScalar returns an object which cannot be assigned to an Integer. Please turn on Option Strict. This is a 2 part process. First for the current project - In Solution Explorer double click My Project. Choose Compile on the left. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. Second for future projects - Go to the Tools Menu -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. This will save you from bugs at runtime.

Comment: @Mary I am sorry for the late response, I have modified my code to reflect Jay's answer below. However now it is not returning values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already accepted an answer, I assumed your problem was solved. My function would look like this.

```
Private Function CountMissedParts() As DataTable
    Dim sql = "SELECT [M/Y OF LOG], COUNT([Missed Part]) As Total 
                FROM [Data Collection] 
                WHERE [MISSED PART] = 'MISSED PART' GROUP BY [M/Y OF LOG]  
                ORDER BY [M/Y OF LOG];"
    Using dt As New DataTable
        Using connection As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Database1.accdb"),
        command As New OleDbCommand(sql, connection)
            connection.Open()
            Using reader = command.ExecuteReader
                dt.Load(reader)
            End Using
        End Using
        Return dt
    End Using
End Function
```

Usage.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim dt = CountMissedParts()
    'Add a grid to your form just to see what data was returned
    'If all is well delete grid and the following line
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
    'To show you how to access the data
    'Inside the For loop is where you would put the code to fill you graph
    For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
        Debug.Print($"{row("M/Y OF LOG")}  -  {row("Total")}")
    Next
End Sub
```

BTW, if the previous answer didn't work, you can click the check again and choose another answer.

Comment: Thank you, Mary; this worked! Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 0):

A small caveat: I don't have much experience with Charts, but the other stuff should be fine.

The important parts are:

> ```
> Dim logDates() As DateTime ...
> ```

This declares an array of DateTime. An array is a simple way to store multiple values of the same type when you intend to loop through the values. I also took the liberty of using the VB.Net DateTime type to explicitly state the Year, Month, and Date values. This method will make things much clearer for you and others reading your code.

> ```
> For counter As Integer = 0 To logDates.Count - 1
> ```

The database command is executed 12 times, once for each entry in the array.

> ```
>    Using Command As New OleDbCommand(sql, connection)
>        Command.Parameters.Add("MY_OF_LOG", OleDbType.Date).Value = logDates(counter)
>        Dim returnValue = Command.ExecuteScalar()
>
>        Dim count As Integer = Integer.Parse(returnValue.ToString)
>
>        ' other points
>        NotInEpicorCHRT.Series("Missed Part").Points.AddXY(counter + 1, count)
>    End Using
> ```

The return value of ExecuteScalar is then put in to the Chart series using the index you originall

---

The whole code suggestion is below:

```vb
    Public Sub CountMissedParts()
        Dim logDates() As DateTime = {New DateTime(2021, 1, 1),
                                      New DateTime(2021, 2, 1),
                                      New DateTime(2021, 3, 1),
                                      New DateTime(2021, 4, 1),
                                      New DateTime(2021, 5, 1),
                                      New DateTime(2021, 6, 1),
                                      New DateTime(2021, 7, 1),
                                      New DateTime(2021, 8, 1),
                                      New DateTime(2021, 9, 1),
                                      New DateTime(2021, 10, 1),
                                      New DateTime(2021, 11, 1),
                                      New DateTime(2021, 12, 1)}

        ' set 0,0
        NotInEpicorCHRT.Series("Missed Part").Points.AddXY(0, 0)

        Using connection As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Database1.accdb")
            connection.Open()

            For counter As Integer = 0 To logDates.Count - 1
                Dim sql = $"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DataCollection WHERE [MISSED PART] = 'Missed Part' AND [M/Y OF LOG] = @MY_OF_LOG;"
                Using Command As New OleDbCommand(sql, connection)
                    Command.Parameters.Add("MY_OF_LOG", OleDbType.Date).Value = logDates(counter)
                    Dim returnValue = Command.ExecuteScalar()

                    Dim count As Integer = Integer.Parse(returnValue.ToString)

                    ' other points
                    NotInEpicorCHRT.Series("Missed Part").Points.AddXY(counter + 1, count)
                End Using
            Next
        End Using

        NotInEpicorCHRT.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Minimum = 0.0
        NotInEpicorCHRT.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Maximum = 12
        NotInEpicorCHRT.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Interval = 1
        NotInEpicorCHRT.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.Minimum = 0.0
        NotInEpicorCHRT.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.Maximum = 45
        NotInEpicorCHRT.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.Interval = 5
    End Sub
```

Comment: If you need further explanation, please do ask

Comment: @JayV  Would this sub replace my entire function?

Comment: @JayV Also, would this sub still only input the values as a y coordinate?

Comment: @Peachy I think it will replace the entire function, what you had in your original function is functionally still there in my version. And, Yes, it does still add the values as a Y coordinate

Comment: @JayV Thank you for the clarification, I'll give it a shot and report back. I appreciate your help!

Comment: You should create the command and add the parameter only once outside of the loop then change the value inside the loop.

Comment: Actually, the data could be retrieved with a single hit to the database with `"SELECT [M/Y OF LOG], COUNT([Missed Part]) As Total FROM [Data Collection] WHERE [MISSED PART] = 'MISSED PART' GROUP BY [M/Y OF LOG]  ORDER BY [M/Y OF LOG];"` which was my answer to the OP's last question.

Comment: @Mary Do you happen to have an idea as to why, out of the blue, the code submitted by Jay would not submit info into the graph? Now no information appears even whenever I debug the program.

Comment: @Mary where should I insert the code you recommended from December 24?

Comment: @Peachy See my answer to this question.